# Convert Cumulative Returns to Daily Returns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I am trying to go from cumulative returns given by

```
hist_data = (hist_data - hist_data.iloc[0]) / hist_data.iloc[0]
```

And I am trying to go from this cumulative return to daily returns but am blanking on how to do this effectively. Any ideas?
I thought this might work if I subtract by one

```
(hist_data[1:] - hist_data[:-1]) / hist_data[:-1]
```

Comment: Can you add the sample data?

Answer (score 5):

If `hist_data` contains the cumulative returns, then this is a common shortcut for computing daily returns.  Assuming `hist_data` is a vector of return percentages, you will need to add `1.0` to hist_data, as I have done below.  This way we have a vector of return ratios instead of return percentages.

```
import numpy as np

daily_returns = np.exp(np.log(hist_data + 1.0).diff())
```

Here we are simply using the property of natural logs (`ln`) that says

```
ln(a/b) = ln(a) - ln(b)
   a/b  = exp(ln(a) - ln(b))
```